# Reference materials on hyperspheres

Tags: general-topology, geometry, reference-request

Anyone have a good reference for various facts about [hyperspheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersphere), either permanent online (such as a book/paper on arXiv, or, say a trusted site such as Wolfram MathWorld) or printed (book or journal)?

The reason I ask is that I couldn't find the source on the [wikipedia page for hypersphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersphere) for material contained in the "Spherical Coordinates" and "Spherical Volume Element" subsections of that page.  None of the listed sources at the bottom of the page seem to have it.  The [Wolfram MathWorld page for hypersphere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html) doesn't even have the aforementioned facts (and the references it contains aren't helpful either).

Comment: For references that specifically relate to the surface area and volume of an $n$-sphere, see the list I posted in [this 22 June 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3814018). Note also [the slight addition/correction](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3814023) I made a few minutes later to my comment near the end that begins with *For more even precise estimates ...*

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the comment, however, there is plenty of sources on calculating the volume/area of an $n$-sphere (as you point out in your post on sci.math).  I am looking for a reference to the derivation of the volume *element* (for integration of a function over a volume of the $n$-sphere) and the spherical coordinates. The citations to wikipedia articles is frowned upon in the academic lit, and I think it's kind of silly (not to mention pretentios if someone else already has done it) to re-derive the whole thing using the Jacobian (even if it'll go into the appendix).

Comment: I suspect what you're looking for is in Richard Courant and Fritz John's **Introduction to Calculus and Analysis**, Volume II (around pages 440 to 460).